# HTML Dialog - Close the dialog box when the background is clicked

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I've been trying to use the [`<dialog>` element in HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) to do modals instead of doing them custom.

One thing that I can't seem to figure out how, if the user would be to click on the background of the modal, to close the modal.

Is there a way to do so?

Here is a very basic JS of what I'm doing to create a dialog/modal

```js
const showButton = document.getElementById("showDialog");
const favDialog = document.getElementById("favDialog");

// "Show the dialog" button opens the <dialog> modally
showButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  favDialog.showModal();
});
```

```html
<!-- A modal dialog containing a form -->
<dialog id="favDialog">
  <form>
    <p>
      <label>
        Favorite animal:
        <select>
          <option value="default">Choose…</option>
          <option>Brine shrimp</option>
          <option>Red panda</option>
          <option>Spider monkey</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </p>
    <div>
      <button value="cancel" formmethod="dialog">Cancel</button>
      <button id="confirmBtn" value="default">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</dialog>
<p>
  <button id="showDialog">Show the dialog</button>
</p>
<output></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `close()` method on your JS code to close the modal if the user clicks on the background.

```
const showButton = document.getElementById("showDialog");
const favDialog = document.getElementById("favDialog");

// "Show the dialog" button opens the <dialog> modally
showButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  favDialog.showModal();
});

favDialog.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target === favDialog) {
    favDialog.close();
  }
});
```

Comment: I'll test it, but wouldnt that close the dialog if you click on the dialog, at all?

Answer (score 0):

Create an [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/eventlistener) on the `<dialog>` in order to listen for changes, and upon click, use [`close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/close) method as [Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21948744) indicated to close the modal.

```js
const showButton = document.getElementById("showDialog");
const favDialog = document.getElementById("favDialog");

// "Show the dialog" button opens the <dialog> modally
showButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  favDialog.showModal();
});

favDialog.addEventListener("click", () => {
  favDialog.close();
});
```

```html
<!-- A modal dialog containing a form -->
<dialog id="favDialog">
  <form>
    <p>
      <label>
        Favorite animal:
        <select>
          <option value="default">Choose…</option>
          <option>Brine shrimp</option>
          <option>Red panda</option>
          <option>Spider monkey</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </p>
    <div>
      <button value="cancel" formmethod="dialog">Cancel</button>
      <button id="confirmBtn" value="default">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</dialog>
<p>
  <button id="showDialog">Show the dialog</button>
</p>
<output></output>
```